# php cURL silent option?

Tags: php, curl

I was using `curl` from shell scripts and was setting `-s` option to make to make it silent
How to set this option in php curl?

Comment: Why do you need a silent option in PHP?  Curl doesn't output anything, so what does it have to be silent about?

Comment: @ircmaxell what? curl_exec outputs the response body to stdout by default!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the CURLOPT_MUTE setting when initializing the connection:

```
curl_setopt($curl_resource, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
```

Comment: This is deprecated!

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution prior to it's deprecation (I believe). Regardless, the correct answer today is below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497400/345152

Answer (score 25):

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

In recent versions of php, `CURLOPT_MUTE` has (probably) been deprecated. Any attempt of using `curl_setopt()` to set `CURLOPT_MUTE` will give you a warning like this:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_MUTE - assumed 'CURLOPT_MUTE' in ....

If you wish to silence the curl output, use the following instead:

```
<?php
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
?>
```

And then,

```
<?php
    $curl_output=curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

The output of the curl operation will be stored as a string in `$curl_output` while the operation remains totally silent.

Answer (score 5):

This post is pretty old, but for future people looking for this answer, you need to use these two options in the current version of php5-curl:

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
?>
```

The first option returns the raw response from curl_exec() so it can be assigned to a variable. The second option prevents curl_exec() from printing the response.

Comment: This does not stop the messages like "< HTTP/1.1 200 OK" yada-yada which curl spews out to the console. Is there a way to stop this, too?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `CURLOPT_MUTE` has been deprecated in recent versions of php.

I'm using PHP 5.3.6 and I'm getting `Use of undefined constant CURL_MUTE - assumed 'CURL_MUTE'` whenever I try to set this option.

Answer (score 0):

there.

If you want to reset your curl handle use `curl_reset($curl_handle)`.

`CURLOPT_MUTE` has been deprecated in recent versions of php